# Got ConnectionException while implementing bulk api

Tags: bulk-api

i tried implementing an example of bulk api provided at below link :
 http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-bulkapi-demo/source/browse/trunk/demo/src/com/jeffdouglas/BulkLoader.java

At run time, i am getting following **error** :

com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0

How can i solve it, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to set a proxy to access the Internet? If you can access https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0 from your browser (you'll see error 405, but this is expected - the SOAP service isn't expecting an HTTP GET), but you can't ping www.salesforce.com from the command line, this is probably the case.

If so, you can fix this by adding the a setProxy call in the `getRestConnection()` method (after line 256):

```
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
partnerConfig.setPassword(password);
partnerConfig.setProxy("host.domain.com", 80); // Change hostname and port as appropriate
partnerConfig
    .setAuthEndpoint("https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/17.0");
```

Comment: Thanks Metadaddy,

now i am stuck due to another error : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input stream can not be null"

Please help.